Inequality between length of confidence intervals
For given statistical model $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{B},\mathcal{P})$, where $\mathcal{P}=\{B(1,\theta)^{\otimes n}:\theta\in (0,1)=\Theta \}$, $B(1,\theta)$ is a Bernoulli-trial with success probability $\theta$, we can show that:
$$C=\left(\overline{x}_n-\frac{u_{1-\alpha/2}}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{\overline{x}_n(1-\overline{x}_n)},\overline{x}_n+\frac{u_{1-\alpha/2}}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{\overline{x}_n(1-\overline{x}_n)}\right)$$
$$D=\left(\sin^2(\arcsin(\sqrt{\overline{x}_n})-\frac{u_{1-\alpha/2}}{2\sqrt{n}}),\sin^2(\arcsin(\sqrt{\overline{x}_n})+\frac{u_{1-\alpha/2}}{2\sqrt{n}})\right)$$
are asymptotical confidence intervals for $\theta$ with confidence level $1-\alpha$, where $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and $u_{\beta}$ is the $\beta$-quantile of the standard-normal distribution, $\beta \in (0,1)$.
I am trying to show that:
$$\lambda (D) \leq \lambda (C)$$
where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue-measure on $\mathbb{R}$, in other words that the interval $C$ has greater or equal length than $D$.
Following is what I have done so far:
$\begin{align*}
0 \leq \lambda (D) &= |\lambda (D)|\\ &= |\sin^2(\arcsin(\sqrt{\overline{x}_n})+\frac{u_{1-\alpha/2}}{2\sqrt{n}})-\sin^2(\arcsin(\sqrt{\overline{x}_n})-\frac{u_{1-\alpha/2}}{2\sqrt{n}})| \\ &\leq |\arcsin(\sqrt{\overline{x}_n})+\frac{u_{1-\alpha/2}}{2\sqrt{n}}|^2 + |\arcsin(\sqrt{\overline{x}_n})-\frac{u_{1-\alpha/2}}{2\sqrt{n}}|^2 \\ & \leq |\arcsin(\sqrt{\overline{x}_n})|^2+|\frac{u_{1-\alpha/2}}{2\sqrt{n}}|^2 + |\arcsin(\sqrt{\overline{x}_n})|^2+|\frac{u_{1-\alpha/2}}{2\sqrt{n}}|^2 \\ &\leq 2\left(|\arcsin(\sqrt{\overline{x}_n})|^2+\frac{|u_{1-\alpha/2}|^2}{4n}\right)\\ & \dots \\ &\leq 2\frac{u_{1-\alpha/2}}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{\overline{x}_n(1-\overline{x}_n)} \\ &= \lambda(C)
\end{align*}$
Here I used the triangle-inequality and $|\sin(x)|\leq|x|$.
I don't know how to proceed to get to the final inequality, any hint or different approach is greatly appreciated!

We use following identities/inequalities:
$$\begin{gather}\\sin^2(x)=\frac{1-cos(x)}{2}  \\ \\ cos(\alpha \pm \beta)= cos(\alpha)cos(\beta)\mp sin(\beta)sin(\alpha)\\ \\sin(2y)=2sin(y)cos(y) \\ \\ cos(arcsin(z))=\sqrt{1-z^2}\\ \\ |sin(x)| \leq |x| \quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}
\end{gather}$$
Let $a=\arcsin(\sqrt{\overline{x_n}})$ and $b=\frac{u_{1-\alpha/2}}{2\sqrt{n}}$ we get:
$\begin{align*}
0 \leq \lambda (D) &= |\lambda (D)|\\ \\&= \left|\sin^2(\arcsin(\sqrt{\overline{x}_n})+\frac{u_{1-\alpha/2}}{2\sqrt{n}})-\sin^2(\arcsin(\sqrt{\overline{x}_n})-\frac{u_{1-\alpha/2}}{2\sqrt{n}})\right| \\ \\ &= |\sin^2(a+b)-\sin^2(a-b)|\\ \\ & =\left|\frac{1-cos(2(a+b))-1+cos(2(a-b))}{2} \right| \\ \\& = \left|\frac{1-cos(2a)cos(2b)+sin(2a)sin(2b)-1+cos(2a)cos(2b)+sin(2a)sin(2b)}{2} \right|\\ \\ & =\left|sin(2a)sin(2b)\right|  \\ \\ & = \left|2sin(a)cos(a)sin(2b)\right|\\ \\ & = 2\left|\sqrt{\overline{x_n}}\sqrt{1-\overline{x_n}}\right|\left|sin(2b)\right| \\ \\ &\leq 2\left|\sqrt{\overline{x_n}(1-\overline{x_n})}\right|\left|2\frac{u_{1-\alpha/2}}{2\sqrt{n}}\right| \\ \\&= \left| 2\frac{u_{1-\alpha/2}}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{\overline{x}_n(1-\overline{x}_n)} \right| \\ \\ &= \left| \lambda(C)\right| \\ \\ &= \lambda(C)
\end{align*}$
